# Scheme: removing something from a list and updating priorities

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to implement sort of a shopping list/queue type of function. The function that I'm having some problems with is removeByPriority. I would like to pass in a number and a list of an item to remove. If it is not in the list, then just return the list, but if it is in the list, then remove it, and then return a list with the priorities updated.

For example, (removePriority 2 shopping-list) would return:

```
=> (("Apple" 3) ("Milk" 2) ("Eggs" 1))
```

I have created some helper functions that do work, and can successfully check whether a certain priority is or isn't in the list, but I am stuck there.

```
#lang scheme

(define shopping-list '( ("Apple" 4) ("Orange" 2)  ("Milk" 3) ("Eggs" 1)) )

(define name (lambda (m)
               (car m)
               ))

(define priority (lambda (m)
                   (car (cdr m))
                   ))

(define containsPriority
  (lambda (k lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst)#f)
      ((equal? k (priority (car lst)))#t)
      (else (containsPriority k (cdr lst)))
      )
    )
  )

(removeByPriority k lst)

(define removeByPriority
  (lambda (k lst)
    (if((not(containsPriority k lst))lst)
       (equal? k (priority(car lst)))
           (else(removeByPriority k (cdr lst))(cons (car lst)))
        )
      )
    )

(removeByPriority 2 shopping-list)
```

Comment: In your example, `"Eggs"` should have a priority of `0`, because all the priorities should be decremented, right?

Comment: In this case, I am just reducing the priorities if they are greater than the one removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use existing procedures whenever possible, also a couple of your procedures can be simplified a bit more. For starters, these are simpler and equivalent to what you wrote:

```
(define name car)
(define priority cadr)

(define (containsPriority k lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #f)
        ((equal? (priority (car lst)) k) #t)
        (else (containsPriority k (cdr lst)))))
```

Here's the interesting part. After checking, we *filter* the value we don't want and afterwards we *map* over the resulting list, decreasing the priorities:

```
(define (removeByPriority k lst)
  (if (not (containsPriority k lst))
      lst
      (map (lambda (pair)
             (list (name pair)
                   (if (< (priority pair) k)
                       (priority pair)
                       (sub1 (priority pair)))))
           (filter-not (lambda (pair)
                         (equal? (priority pair) k))
                       lst))))
```

It works as requested:

```
(define shopping-list '(("Apple" 4) ("Orange" 2)  ("Milk" 3) ("Eggs" 1)))
(removeByPriority 2 shopping-list)
=> '(("Apple" 3) ("Milk" 2) ("Eggs" 1))
```

Comment: Very helpful! I just need to see how I can get priorities lower than the one I am removing to stay the same. Thank you!

Comment: Best answer indeed! Very much appreciated!!

Comment: Just a few questions for my own clarity. I'm not familiar with sub1 and filter-not. I assume sub1 is just a function name? Also, is "filter-not" a specific scheme function? Edit: sub1 just means to subtract 1. I understand that.

Comment: @user2411290 `(sub1 x)` is the same as `(- x 1)`, `filter-not` is Racket-specific and is the same as a `filter` where the predicate is negated.